# Can not send 100 MB videos over URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

This function will send small videos only. How do I change this to send 100 MB videos? The server limits are set to 200 MB.  When uploading the video I send the file path for the video to a SQL Db and the video with a unique id to the file manager.  If the video is less then 5MB it returns the massage added successfully and if the video is over 5MB there's no video in the file manager. I have tried to get this but I can't work it out.

From what I understand Swift/NSURLSession will not load large amounts into memory.

Can someone show my how to convert this to work.

```
func uploadVideo2 (){


    //Bool to control Post Activity Indicator.isHidden
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.videoOnOff = "on"
    self.postActivityIndicatorIsHidden()
    })

    //Here we get the card's UUID to be used with the param
    let unquieID  =  theDictionary.value(forKey: "unquieID") as! String

    // param to be sent in body. This will be used in the $_request variable in the DBVideo.php
    let param = ["videoUnquieID" : unquieID] //This is the card's UUID

    // url path to php file
    let url = URL(string: "xxxx://xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx/xxx/DBVideo.php")!

    // Adding the url to the request variable
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    // Declare POST method
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // Assign video to videoData variable
    let videoData = theDictionary.value(forKey: "theVideo") as! Data

    // Creat a UUID for the boundary as a string
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

    //Set the request value to multipart/form-data     the boundary is the UUID string
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    request.httpBody = createBodyWithParamsVideo(param, //This is the card's UUID
                                                 filePathKey: "file", //The path to the variable $_FILES in the DBVideo.php
                                                 imageDataKey: videoData as Data, //The video's data from the card
                                                 boundary: boundary) // A unquie ID setup just for the baundary

    // launch session
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if response != nil {
        }

        // get main queue to communicate back to user
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    // json containes $returnArray from php  //converting resonse to NSDictionary
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.videoOnOff = "off" //Controls for the Activity indicator
                    self.postActivityIndicatorIsHidden() //Activity indicator
                    })


                    // declare new parseJSON to store json
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.contactImageOnOff = "off" //Controls for the Activity indicator
                        self.postActivityIndicatorIsHidden() //Activity indicator
                        })
                        return
                    }

                    var msg : String!

                    //getting the json response
                    msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                    //printing the response
                    print(msg)


                    // error while jsoning
                } catch {
                     let message = error
                    print(message)
                 }

                // error with php
            } else {
                //no nothing
            }
        })
        }.resume()
}
```

Here is the PHP

```
    <?php

    //STEP 1. Check to see if data was passed to this php file
    if (empty($_REQUEST['videoUnquieID'])) {
        $returnArray["massage"] = "Missing required information";
    return;
    }

    // Pass POST via htmlencryot and assign to $id
    $id = htmlentities($_REQUEST['videoUnquieID']);


    //STEP 2. Createing the $folder variable to hold the path where the video will be placed
    $folder = "VBCVideo/";


    //STEP 3. Move uploaded file
    $folder = $folder . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder)) {
        $returnArray["status"]="200";
        $returnArray["message"]="The Video file has been uploaded";
    } else {
        $returnArray["status"]="300";
        $returnArray["message"]="Error while uploading the Video";
    }


     //STEP 4. Build connection
     //Constructor to create connection
        function __construct()
        {
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
            require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
            // opening db connection
            $db = new DbConnect();
            $this->connect = $db->connect();
        }


     // STEP 5. Feedback array to app user
     echo json_encode($returnArray);

     ?>
```

php.ini

```
    max_execution_time = 500000;
    upload_max filesize = 200000M;
    post_max_size = 400000M;
    memory_limit = 200000m;
```

Comment: You need to divide video into 3mb part and then upload those part to server.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to send a 100MB video?

Comment: @dscrown please debug your code tell us exact error.

Comment: @ Nazmul: I am not sure how I would divide the video and reassemble.  The server gets everything but the larger video with no errors.

Comment: You need to add more detail about what **specifically** is going wrong. All you've said is "not working correctly", which is extremely vague.

Comment: Tom: I have updated the details.

Comment: No Error on small video only on large video.  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0

Comment: It's probably a server error, you can increase the `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time` variables to allow file uploads of 200Mb

Comment: I have updated the question to show the php.ini

Comment: FYI: I don't care if this is converted to Alamofire at this point as long as I have a working solution. Alamofire and php